# How to remove "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" from response headers in apache conf

Tags: apache

In my website it displays "Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8  in response headers. please help me with the configuration that i need to to in apache to hide/remove this.

Comment: Most likely this is not an Apache question - we'll need to know what generates the content and how it all is configured. And if there's no custom code involved it'll be hard to argue for this question to be on topic on stackoverflow.